# Newly installed IIS 7.5 incorrectly serving up blank pages for ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am trying to troubleshoot why my newly installed IIS is not properly serving my ASP.net application. Right now I am running it locally, and trying to connect to it from a browser.

The Bindings for the site are *:80 (http), and it is the only Site currently Started within my IIS. The address being used from within in browser is localhost or the computername. I have also tried connecting to the computer from another computer on the same network using the computername, and get the same blank page.

If I change the bindings to something else, like jrqmzed.com on *:80 (http), then when connecting to those same addresses from within a browser I get:

`HTTP Error 404: The requested resource is not found.`

If I stop the site, then when connecting to those same addresses from within a browser I get:

`This site can't be reached` in Chrome, and

`Unable to connect` in Firefox.

From searching online thus far, I have ensured that my IIS is set to serve Static Content. For sanity sake, I currently has all options checked under "Turn Windows features on or off" > "Internet Information Services" except FTP Server.

I am running 64bit Windows 7 Professional. The ASP.net application currently works on a separate computer with IIS 7.5, and I could not immediately notice any difference in settings between that computer's IIS and my newly installed IIS.

How else can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: ASP.NET 4 requires manual registration on IIS via aspnet_regiis. Search for the utility explanation on MSDN and follow it.

Comment: Two things. If you haven't already, just put a regular .html file with like "Hello World" in it so you can make sure that the IIS setup at a base level is working. Then in IIS check the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions. If you see the version of ASP.NET there that you want (bearing in mind that 2.0 is what you see for 3.5 and 4.0 also covers 4.5) make sure that it 's set to "Allowed". If the version you want is not there, you don't necessarily need to do the aspnet_regiis thing, you can usually install the version via the windows features section you used to install IIS.

Comment: @LexLi It was as easy as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET 4 requires manual registration on IIS 7/7.5 via aspnet_regiis.

Search for the utility explanation on MSDN and follow it.

Comment: I can confirm with a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 the .NET Framework 4.7.2 is installed by default. However after installing the IIS role you will notice that ASP.NET 4 ISAPI filters will not be registered in IIS resulting in blank pages when dynamic content is requested.  Running aspnet_regiis (I used the -i parameter) registers the filters and fixes the issue.  Why this is not done as part of the IIS installation is beyond me.

Comment: @JeremyF that's probably because .NET Framework 4.x should come from Windows Update, and that's only the runtime for desktop applications. `aspnet_regiis` is still needed to register it on IIS.